# VS 2012 C++ - Project-to-project references that may not be a part of the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dependencies

Note: applies to C++ only.

*Background: While porting a huge solution of projects from VS 2008 to 2012 we face the challenge of adjusting the project references to the new VS 2010+ style. In VS 2008 you could create a link-time reference to another C++ library module and it was stored into the solution file as 'Project dependencies'. In 2012, these influence only the build order but in order to create a link-time reference it must be added via [References...] which are now stored per-project .*

Now the problem: since in VS2010+ project-to-project references are stored in project file instead of solution, if someone adds a project with references to another solution without manually adding also each of the references projects, this **breaks the solution** (but allows you to do it) and we get the infamous "***Project file '' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution***" error on every attempt to build without even including the name of the project. Seems VS is not prepared for this. Unfortunately, with over 300 projects dependent on each other in our solution, we do need to also allow to split it into smaller parts for convenience of many programmers.

Does anyone know of a way to define the C++ library reference such that it does not break the solution when you load it and the referenced projects are not a part of it? I know the reference still won't work in such case and we're perfectly willing to deal with that (let the person creating a new solution specify it manually as linker inputs) but getting this error message (that does not tell where the problem is) is unacceptable and bars our attempt to migrate from 2008 to 2012. We want to have a complete, huge solution that is used by an automated MSBuild process to build everything yet still have an option to include some of the projects into smaller solutions without getting this error.

I was doing research on how to specify a satisfying conditional expression on 
`<ProjectReference Include="..\..\xxx\ProjectName.vcxproj" Condition="...">` - if we could only specify an expression that processes this only if the vcxproj is part of the solution currently loaded so we don't trigger the error. Does anyone have any experience with it? Or is there a better way to approach this? 
In 2008, the references being specified in the .sln instead of .vcproj, you simply had to redo them all over again in any additional solution. Time-consuming and irritating, but at least you did not get a showstopper error that does not tell you the culprit once you included a project with dependencies.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Having delved deeper in MSBuild functionality I found out that we can include the project reference only for a specific SolutionFileName easily and it does get rid of the error. But is there a possibility for a more robust solution that will detect whether the included project is part of the currently loaded solution and Exclude it if not? It would be nice if the smaller solutions still got at least some of the dependences.

Comment: This is just doesn't scale that well for such large solutions.  Just specify the link dependency directly, Linker + Input, Additional Dependencies.  That way it also works when you create small solutions from the large one without having to make any changes at all.